# Can did I launch process separate of main process? In bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I try launch project on server and send query to him:

similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar patch/p-SNAPSHOR.jar
curl -d localhost/go/param
```

the script launches p-SNAPSHOT.jar and stops - waits for a request. I can did him from another console, or remote. But in this case I need did that in next string.

---

### How can I make it possible for run a project and send a request to it?

Comment: If you want to start a program and detach it from the shellscript, so that the shellscript can continue with its next program (or command line), you can add an ampersand, `&`, at the end of its command line. Maybe it will work with `java -jar patch/p-SNAPSHOR.jar &`

Comment: It is a similar that what I need.